# Can I make a window not resize itself until the user lets go of the mouse button?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some screens with a lot of stuff on them, and the redrawing performance is pretty poor. It is possible to set a form into a resizing mode where a rectangle is shown on the screen that denotes the new window dimensions as the user resizes it, but the actual form doesn't resize until they let go of the mouse button?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes; this behavior is defined by one of the window styles, which you can turn on/off using the `Control.SetStyles` method. In particular, I think you want this:

```
myForm.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, false);
```

You could then hook the mousedown/resize/mouseup events and force the redraw to happen when you wanted.

You can also try turning on the double buffering style:

```
myForm.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
```

See this article for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkf25009(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: setstyle doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: you may need to call UpdateStyles after you change the style.

Answer (score 1):

Completely suppressing all drawing is not practical, the window frame painting is out of your direct control.  Nor is it necessary, all you have to do is make your drawing fast when the form is being resized.  Like this:

```
    private bool fastRender;

    protected override void OnResizeBegin(EventArgs e) {
        fastRender = true;
        base.OnResizeBegin(e);
    }

    protected override void OnResizeEnd(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnResizeEnd(e);
        fastRender = false;
        this.Invalidate();
    }
```

And check the *fastRender* variable in your Paint event handler, drawing only the minimum.  Or nothing at all.  If the actual delay is caused by a large number of controls then tackle that by making them invisible in ResizeBegin and visible again in ResizeEnd.  Easy to do with a Panel.  If it is caused by a controls that are docked or have the Anchor set so that they'll resize or move whenever the user resizes the window then you'll find Suspend/ResumeLayout useful.

Comment: In my case, it's a very large, docked, datagridview that really slows things down.

Comment: I just thought back to the days of windows 95 where there was a nice rectangle that showed the dimensions of the new window, and when you let go the window resized to fit that. I don't recall when exactly it changed to drawing the window again for each increment of the resize.

Comment: If it is just a docked DGV then calling SuspendLayout in OnResizeBegin and ResumeLayout(true) in OnResizeEnd() will work very well.  The DGV won't repaint while you resize the window so it will be silky smooth.

Comment: There's a lot of black space when i do this though, what would I have to do to change that to the proper background color?

Comment: Change the form's BackColor property.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the DoubleBuffer feature of a winform/control?

Comment: I used a special trick that supposedly double buffers every control on the screen. I have very little flicker now, but the resizing performance is horrible.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `ResizeEnd` instead of `Resize`.

Answer (score 0):

Open the window that is abnormally sized; then hold down the control key, hit the <kbd>+</kbd> key until you return to your required size. Good luck.